# Ruby while loop with integers

Tags: ruby

Get input for a number < 100, if input is greater then keep looping until you get a correct input.
Do a check to see if the number is even or odd, if it's even then * 2 if it's odd * 3.

The code below works, want to know if there is a simpler way to accomplish the same task ?

```
puts "Enter a number less than 100"
number =gets.chomp.to_i 

while number > 100
  
  puts "Enter a number less than 100"
  number = gets.chomp.to_i
 
 if number < 100 && number % 2 == 0
     puts number * 2
 elsif number < 100 && number % 3 == 0
         puts number * 3
 else
     puts " Try again"
end

end
```

Comment: `number % 3 == 0` checks whether number is divisible by 3 (e.g. 3, 6, 9, 12). To check for odd numbers (e.g. 1, 3, 5, 7) you need `number % 2 == 1`. Ruby also has [`odd?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Integer.html#odd-3F-method) / [`even?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Integer.html#even-3F-method)

Answer (score 0):

When code is complex or the logic doesn't feel right, functions are helpful. It's more code, but easier to test and in my mind simpler to follow.

Aiming for more readibility.

```rb
def get_input
 puts "Enter a number less than 100"
 gets.chomp.to_i
end

def calculate(number)
  number.even? ? number * 2 : number * 3
end

def valid_number?(number)
  number > 0 && number < 100
end

def outlier?(number)
  number == 1
end

invalid = true

while invalid
  number = get_input

  if valid_number?(number)
    if outlier?(number)
      puts "Try again"
    else
      puts calculate(number)
      invalid = false
    end
  end
end
```

Shortened form without functions for brevity.

```rb
invalid = true

while invalid
  puts "Enter a number less than 100"
  number = gets.chomp.to_i

  if number > 0 && number < 100
    if number == 1
      puts "Try again"
    else
      puts number.even? ? number * 2 : number * 3
      invalid = false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is good, wanted to stretch the skills only using a while loop.

Comment: @Clarke I shortened even further.

Comment: `number % 2 == 0` is really just `Integer#even?`. However, what will you do when `number == 1`? In the OP's code (which they say is working) it prints " Try again", but your solution would print `3`.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your question what you think the problem is, or what gains you're actually looking for. Since your code is working, this may ultimately be a better fit for Code Review Stack Exchange.

That said, there are certainly *shorter* ways to express your code, and a number of edge cases your code doesn't currently take into account. For reasons I'll enumerate below the code, I'd express this type of prompting loop as follows:

```rb
loop do
  print "\nEnter a number less than 100: "
  number = gets.chomp.to_i

  case 
  when number >= 100
    STDERR.puts %(Try again.)
  when number.zero?
    STDERR.puts %(You can't divide zero!)
    next
  when number.modulo(2).eql?(0)
    p number * 2
  when number.modulo(3).eql?(0)
    p number * 3
  else
    STDERR.puts 'Try again.'
    next
  end

  break if number < 100
end
```

This will:

1. Prompt and re-prompt inside the loop.
2. Avoid the need to assign an initial value to *number* before checking a while/until loop conditional.
3. Improve user feedback and integrate it into the loop.
4. Handle some edge cases, e.g. `0` and `100` as input values.
5. Replace your conditionals with a case statement (which doesn't add a ton of value, but looks cleaner to me).
6. Return the computed value from the case statement with [Kernel#p](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Kernel.html#method-i-p) (rather than `nil` from [Kernel#puts](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Kernel.html#method-i-puts)) while still printing the result to standard output.

There are many other ways to express the central idea in your code, and lots of ways to make the code more modular or compact, but whether they are "better" or "worse" will be contextual and (to a large degree) a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

```
loop do
  puts "Enter a number less than 100"
  number = gets.chomp.to_i
  # the rules interrepted as natural numbers (except zero) < 100
  if (1..99).cover?(number) 
    # we use tap so that the loop will actually return the number
    break (number * (number.even? ? 2 : 3)).tap do |x|
      puts x # because puts returns nil
    end
  else
    puts "Try again"
  end
end
```

Instead of using while or until with a variable dangling off it you can just use Ruby's built in `loop` keyword together with `break`, `redo` and `retry` for control flow. `loop` like everything in Ruby is an expression so it will return the value after `break`.